# Sharepoint - Moving database files to different drive

Tags: sharepoint-server, tfs

I found this technet post moving the database: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40701cb5-05a8-4a8a-9cf2-8be0e632a2f5/moving-sharepoint-database-from-one-drive-to-other?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

As part of the steps it says to stop various sharepoint services, which I have almost completed. The last service it says to stop is the World Wide Web Publishing Service which I have not stopped yet.

My concern is that TFS (version 2010, I know, I know but I didn't set it up) is also running from the same box using the same IIS and I don't want employees to be interrupted, tfs wise (other than sharepoint and SSRS).

My question is will there be any issues with sharepoint (or tfs for that matter) if we DON'T stop the world wide and continue on with the steps in the post?

**FOLLOW UP**

I ended up just needing to stop the sharepoint related sites in IIS instead of shutting down the entire WWW service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its recommended to stop the WWW but if you dont want then you can stop all SharePoint related Web Sites/ App Pools on all servers. this way TFS having no issue.